# Drawing walking path ios

Tags: ios, dictionary

In my application , I would like to implement drawing user walking path therefore, I decided to use breadcrumb that apple provides. In their example code, they initiate crumbview in the following delegate, but my exisiting application also uses the same delegate, now I will have two overlays in one delegate. However, it does not draw on the map.

```
-(MKOverlayView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForOverlay:(id )overlay{

    if (!self.crumbView)
    {
        _crumbView = [[CrumbPathView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
    }
    if([overlay isKindOfClass:[MKPolygon class]])
    {
        MKPolygonView *view = [[MKPolygonView alloc] initWithOverlay:overlay];
        view.lineWidth=4;
        if([[overlay title] isEqualToString:@"world"])
        {

            view.strokeColor = [[UIColor blackColor]colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
        }
        else
        {

            if([colorSch isEqualToString:@"EPAColor"]&&colorvalue>60)
                view.fillColor=[color colorWithAlphaComponent:.2];
            else
            view.fillColor=[color colorWithAlphaComponent:.1];


        }

        return view;
    }
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: I note that this will never return _crumbView, so that layer won't work. Does the polygon display? If not, need to start with the obvious...does this method get called? Does it get called with overlay as an `MKPolygon`?

Comment: MKPolygon works well, but crumbview does not

Answer (score 1):

Then it's easy, just `return self.crumbView` instead of `return nil` at the end (you could also add a test for `CrumbPath` type, but assuming you only have the two views, you don't really need to)

Comment: Odd. Can you post the code where you first add the overlay and the revised code with above fix in it?  Finally, using break points or NSLigs, is the above being called twice?